# vim: where to put default values for plugin variables?

Tags: variables, vim, default, vim-plugin

What is the best way to set default values for plugin variables?

Ideally, I would like to have those variables set before `.vimrc` is loaded, such that the user can override these values if he wants to. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you writing a plugin?

Your plugin will likely be executed after your user's `~/.vimrc`: you can't do anything before that.

You could just forget about doing anything prior to the execution of `~/.vimrc` and use conditionals in your script:

```
if !exists("g:pluginname_optionname")
  let g:pluginname_optionname = default_value
endif
```

Or you could use an autoload script (`:h autoload`) and ask your users to put something like the following in their `~/.vimrc` before any customization:

```
call file_name#function_name()
```

with that function doing all the initialization stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Your plugin should only set the default value if the variable does not exist when the plugin is loaded. You can check this using the `exists()` function.

For example, at the top of your plugin script:

```
if !exists("g:MyPluginVariable")
    let g:MyPluginVariable = default_value
endif
```

Now, if `g:MyPluginVariable` is set in the vimrc, it will not be redefined by your plugin.

Comment: Oooooooh, we even chose the same `default_value`!

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `get()` approach, taking advantage that you can access the global scope `g:` as a `Dictionary`:

```
let g:pluginname#optionname = get(g:, 'pluginname#optionname', default_value)
```

The `get()`  queries the `g:` scope as a `Dictionary` for the key `pluginname#optionname` and will return `default_value` if it cannot find the key there. The `let` statement either reassigns the same value it had or `default_value`.

The advantage is that is shorter if you are using lots of variables with default values in your plugin.